# Gnome desktop goes complete blue and nothing is readable on login

Tags: gnome, 22.04

I tried installing ubuntu 22.04 on my old Lenovo N23 which previously ran Win 10 slow, but fine.

When I click "Try Ubuntu", all of the desktop goes completely blue where all the windows go completely black and nothing is readable. I decided to tackle this by trying out Ubuntu Mate, it works fine but as a tablet/touch device doesn't offer the same interface, and installed gnome-desktop manually using taskel, only to encounter the exact same issue.

I tried running the gnome-desktop on both, weyland and xorg.
I can switch using the login screen back and forth, but once I login using gnome, I have to restart to be see everything properly again.

[logged into gnome desktop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Llu02.jpg)

[what terminal is looking like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1eOi.jpg)

lshw output :

```
lime-lenovo-n23
description: Convertible
product: 80UR (LENOVO_MT_80UR_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo N23)
vendor: LENOVO
version: Lenovo N23
serial: lime
width: 64 bits
capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
configuration: administrator_password=disabled boot=normal chassis=convertible family=IDEAPAD frontpanel_password=disabled keyboard_password=disabled power-on_password=disabled sku=LENOVO_MT_80UR_BU_idea_FM_Lenovo N23 uuid=
*-core
   description: Motherboard
   product: Lenovo N23
   vendor: LENOVO
   physical id: 0
   version: SDK0K13476 WIN
   serial: lime
   slot: Part Component
 *-firmware
      description: BIOS
      vendor: Lenovo
      physical id: 0
      version: 2QCN18WW
      date: 11/04/2016
      size: 128KiB
      capacity: 6MiB
      capabilities: pci upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect pc98 acpi usb biosbootspecification netboot uefi
 *-cpu
      description: CPU
      product: Intel(R) Celeron(R) CPU  N3060  @ 1.60GHz
      vendor: Intel Corp.
      physical id: 7
      bus info: cpu@0
      version: 6.76.4
      serial: To Be Filled By O.E.M.
      slot: CHV
      size: 2480MHz
      capacity: 2480MHz
      width: 64 bits
      clock: 83MHz
      capabilities: lm fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx rdtscp x86-64 constant_tsc arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology tsc_reliable nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx est tm2 ssse3 cx16 xtpr pdcm sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes rdrand lahf_lm 3dnowprefetch epb pti ibrs ibpb stibp tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid tsc_adjust smep erms dtherm ida arat md_clear cpufreq
      configuration: cores=2 enabledcores=2 microcode=1041 threads=2
```

full lshw output here -> https://1drv.ms/t/s!AkXMG5DQqW539DzlMLhx0jcyftDa?e=EI4bMe

Comment: yes @Nmath, I did. with both, the Ubuntu image and the Ubuntu-Mate

Answer (score 0):

I do not know what exactly is causing the issue, but out of curiosity I opened the device and installed an m.2 drive, after that the installation worked perfectly.

The mmc might be corrupt or something, which still doesn't explain why Mate works perfectly and Ubuntu vanilla doesn't; I hope somebody is able to shed some light on it in the future.